# JSX concatenation showing [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to show messages in react application. I am looping through message array and displaying it. But when I loop and generate the JSX it is getting displayed as  `[object Object]`
Below is the code for generating the JSX.

```
for (let i = 0; i < show_page_msg.length; i++) {
        if(show_page_msg[i].type == 'info')
        page_success_msg_str += <div className={`msg`}>
            <div className="" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: show_page_msg[i].msg }}></div>
        </div>
    }
```

But when I remove the concatenation it is showing the message.

```
page_success_msg_str = <div className={`msg`}>
```

Why concatenation is not working?

Comment: Could you make working example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7pog0v9q/  Here when I remove the concatenation `+` it is getting concatenated and showing correctly. But in my application when I remove `+` it shows only the last message.

Comment: Why are you doing something out of Reactjs scope like for loop and creating the element inside it? While using react make sure to use react based approach. Whether displaying of each message in the UI is the requirement?

Comment: Yes. I want to display each message in the UI

Comment: Then check this example https://jsfiddle.net/6twyn0bk/